# Joining a table with multiple tables depending on the value of a column

Tags: mysql, join

I have one central table which has its key spread across multiple tables.

So it would be

```
events (id,event_type,occured_on)
```

event_type can be mandrill, aweber, sendgrid, ses... etc.

the other related tables are :

```
mandrill_events (id,event_id,some columns..)
sendgrid_events (id,event_id,some columns..)
aweber_events (id,event_id,some columns..)
ses_events (id,event_id,some columns..)
```

How do I write a query to get all the events from the events table but join the appropriate table based on the value in the event_type column ?

Comment: Can't you just do a union on specific events table and left join that against the central events table?
SELECT * FROM events e LEFT JOIN (select *,'mandril' as [event_type] from mandril_events union all select *,'sendgrid' as [event_type] from sendgrid_events....) u ON u.event_id = e.id and u.event_type = e.event_type

Comment: @GratusD. there are about 25 different tables for those events.  Would that hamper performance in any way ? Would it be the best way to go about getting my result ?

Comment: Yeah, if individual tables are large, over 100,000 rows, the left join against a non-indexed column (event_type) would be slow. The union is fast and wouldn't matter. The alternative is to specify event_type in the specific tables and index that.